# Is there information available to diagnose DLT2000/4000 POST errors?

Tags: magnetic-tape

I'm trying to read some DLT CompactTape IIIXL tapes.

The Quantum TH3AA (DLT2000XT) drive I have was last working in 2018 but on powerup all the lights illuminate then the lights on the left go out but the lights on the right flash.

I picked up a Quantum TH5AA (DLT4000) drive from eBay and it does the exact same thing.  I can hit the Unload button and it will clear the error and allow me to insert a tape.  It will load the tape and then all the lights on the right will flash and then stay on.

Google and the manuals are only slightly helpful -- this is described as a POST error, possibly a capstan failure.

Is there any more granular information on what this error may be, and is there anything I can do to potentially overcome it (beyond getting another unit off of eBay)?

Comment: Maybe a belt has disintegrated.